# Visual C++ import a .net DLL

Tags: c++, .net, dll

I am trying to import a third party .net DLL library file to my Visual C++ DLL project. I used the regasm to generate a type Library so it can be wrapped around as a COM object. However, the namespace for the .net DLL library is in the format of `com.etag.xxx.` and yet the namespace generated in the `typelib` is `com_etag_xxx`. I tried to use `com::etag::xxx::class` to identify the class object but failed. How do I know if a .net DLL is "interop"?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try using com_etag_xxx::class ?

Comment: This is by design, a period is not valid in a namespace name so the library exporter did the next best thing it could do, replacing them with an underscore.  There is no point in trying to fight that.  But if you insist then just declare your own namespaces in C++ and use the `no_namespace` attribute on the #import directive.